# What does "Prima facie case is not to be confused with prima facie title" mean?

Tags: criminal-law, definition

I do not know much about the law. I know *prima facie* means, but do not understand what it means in this sentence, which comes from an Indian court case:

> "Prima facie case is not to be confused with prima facie title".

What is a *prima facie title*? I have googled it but have not found a relevant answer.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context to this quote?

Comment: @RyanM As my answer says, it's a quote from an Indian case involving an injunction in a long running dispute over the sale of a house. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: @Justaguy Good find, and great answer too!  Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/49480/) is the full sentence:

"*Prima facie case* is not to be confused with *prima facie title* which has to be established, on evidence at the trial."

As you probably know, *prima facie* means "on its face." A *prima facie case* is a case in which one party has presented enough evidence to support a verdict in its favor. A *title* is a document that serves as proof of ownership. A *prima facie title,* is when one doesn't have a title, but has other things that usually indicate one is the owner. Having these things shows, *on their face*, that you are the owner of the property. For example, if you don't have a title, but you have receipts showing you've paid the taxes on the land these may be taken as evidence that you own the property.

The sentence you quote comes from a long running (over 12 year!) dispute involving the sale of a house in India. This particular decision involved a request for a temporary injunction. This sentence is in a paragraph discussing the conditions under which a court can grant an injunction. It appears to be quoted fairly often in other cases.

In this sentence, the court makes two points. First, in order to get an injunction, the plaintiff must make a *prima facie case* that there is a dispute here that needs to be resolved in court. Without such a dispute, there is no reason to enjoin (stop) the defendant from acting until after the court decides. Second, the *prima facie case* that must be made to get an injunction is not the same as the *prima facie title,* which must be proved in court.